# How to setup VBA IDE with multi-tab code windows view

Tags: ms-access-2010, vba7

I'm looking for a workaround to allow the IDE of VBA7 (ms-access 2010) to organize multiple code windows in tabs (multi-tab view), like in most modern code editors.

Do anyone of you guys out there knows a settings or a method to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Pietro

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option, and you are not the first to request a modernised VBE but, sadly, don't expect it to happen.

Often, I cut and paste between the VBE and [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which has decent add-ins for VB(A) and SQL. Not optimal, but useful in some cases.

Comment: I see.. this means that I need to copy the source code out to the VBA IDE, edit it in Visual Studio Code, and then copy back in the VBA IDE, if I understand correctly... a bit cumbersome.
Thanks anyway Gustav.
Regards

Comment: True, in no way fancy, but it is quite fast: _Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, switch window, Ctrl+A, Ctrl+V_.